# What is the percentage of stars with planetary systems

Tags: astronomy, planets, stars, exoplanets

We have discovered quite a number of exoplanets to date. The Kepler spacecraft has examined 150,000 stars and found [1,059 exoplanets](http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/).

We know that Kepler, as well as all other exoplanet searches to date, can only find planets that cross in front of their star. That means that a large percentage of existing planets will not be detected. In addition, a lot of planets may be too small for the sensitivity of our detectors.

From these facts, has anyone calculated the probability of a star having a planetary system? I am guessing it is likely quite close to 1, i.e. all stars have planets, but I have not seen anyone figures for it.

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited on [astronomy.stackexchange.com](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Kitchi no, it's fine here.

Comment: relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24866/what-is-the-probability-that-a-star-of-a-given-spectral-type-will-have-planets?rq=1

Comment: Note that **all** planets cross in front of their star.

Comment: Astrobites [covered](http://astrobites.org/2014/03/10/a-planet-for-every-m-dwarf-star/) [a recent article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0430) on the subject.  You'll find links there to other papers that estimate the frequency of planetary systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several different estimates, based on several factors.  The article [One or more bound planets per Milky Way star
from microlensing observations](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.0903) (Cassan et al. 2011) suggests that your estimate that the probability being close to 1, suggesting that

> One or more bound planets per Milky Way star
>   from microlensing observations

If you take particular types of exoplanets as examples - such as, according to the Keck Observatory article [One in Five (sun like) Stars Has Earth-sized Planet in Habitable Zone](http://www.keckobservatory.org/recent/entry/one_in_five_stars_has_earth_sized_planet_in_habitable_zone) (2013), through a combination of monitoring and modelling, they have determined

> Accounting for missed planets, as well as the fact that only a small fraction of planets are oriented so that they cross in front of their host star as seen from Earth, allowed them to estimate that 22 percent of all sun-like stars in the galaxy have Earth-size planets in their habitable zones.

Comment: Thanks, @Amaterasu. It looks as if my guess was in the ballpark. I have a couple of others as well, e.g. life will be everywhere, but intelligent life will not be found elsewhere in the galaxy. I do not expect an answer to them soon though.