# Relation of fraction of binary stars with spectral class (mass)

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, stars

What is relation of fraction of binary stars with spectral class (mass)? For example, how many binary stars are among O,B,A,F,G,K,M stars separately?

Comment: I feel this is on topic given that we have a well-received question with the exact same structure: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24866/what-is-the-probability-that-a-star-of-a-given-spectral-type-will-have-planets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second paragraph of [this paper by Kouwenhoven *et al.*](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009A%26A...493..979K) has a great summary:

> Practically all O-type stars (Mason et al. 1998) and B/A-type stars (Shatsky & Tokovinin 2002; Kobulnicky & Fryer 2007; Kouwenhoven et al. 2007b) are found in binary or multiple systems. Abt & Levy (1976) report a multiplicity fraction of 55% among F3−G2 stars, and in their CORAVEL spectroscopic study of F7−G9 stars, Duquennoy & Mayor (1991) find a binary fraction of ∼60%. The binary fraction among M-type stars is 30−40% (Fischer & Marcy 1992; Leinert et al. 1997; Reid & Gizis 1997). For late M-type stars and brown dwarfs the binary fraction decreases to 10−30% (e.g., Gizis et al. 2003; Close et al. 2003; Bouy et al. 2003; Burgasser et al. 2003; Siegler et al. 2005; Ahmic et al. 2007; Maxted et al. 2008; Joergens 2008).

(Note those references can be found easily on the SAO/NASA ADS [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-ref_query?bibcode=2009A%26A...493..979K&refs=REFERENCES&db_key=AST).)

The rest of the paper describes some of the subtleties at work when astronomers combine modeling with observational data.

Answer (score 1):

One should be careful about the selection effects here.  For example for an F star to have an M companion, we call it an F star in a binary system.  But when a sample of M stars is compiled, people looked for companions fainter than the main targets...